# find total of matching category names

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, for-loop, foreach

I have a xml file whose data looks something like this

```
<Companies>
  <Company>
     <Name>Company123</Name>
     <Sales>
       <Sale>
         <Code>Sale123</Code>
         <Category>Apple</Category>
         <Amount>150.50</Amount>
       </Sale>
       <Sale>
         <Code>Sale234</Code>
         <Category>Mango</Category>
         <Amount>170.50</Amount>
       </Sale>
       <Sale>
         <Code>Sale345</Code>
         <Category>Apple</Category>
         <Amount>160.50</Amount>
       </Sale>
     </Sales>
   </Company>
   <Company>
    //other values
   </Company>
</Companies>
```

Here is the class I have to store this information

```
public class Companies 
    {
        public Companies()
        {
            AllCompanies = new List<Company>();
        }

        public List<Company> AllCompanies;

    }
    public class Company
    {
        public Company()
        {
            Saleses = new List<Sales>();
        }

        public string Name;
        public string Code;
        public double MaintenancePercentage;
        public double AverageSales;
        public double TotalSales;
        public double TotalMaintenanceFee;
        public List<Sales> Saleses;

    }
    public class Sales
    {
        public string Code;
        public string Title;
        public DateTime DateTime;
        public string Category;
        public double Amount;
    }
```

Right now I've been able to find total sales for a company, but I don't know how to find total sales for same categories.
Here is sample code of what i've done

```
var companies = (from c in doc.Descendants("Company")
                           select c).ToList();
            foreach (var xCompany in companies)
            {
                var sales = (from xElement in xCompany.Descendants("Sale") select xElement).ToList();

                var company = new Company()
                    {
                        Name = ((from x in xCompany.Descendants("Name") select x.Value).First()),
                        Code = (from x in xCompany.Descendants("Code") select x.Value).First(),
                        MaintenancePercentage =
                            Convert.ToDouble((from x in xCompany.Descendants("MaintenancePercentage") select x.Value).First())
                    };
                for (int index = 0; index < sales.Count; index++)
                {
                    var xElement = sales[index];
                    var sale = new Sales()
                        {
                            Code = ((from x in xElement.Descendants("Code") select x.Value).First()),
                            Title = ((from x in xElement.Descendants("Title") select x.Value).First()),
                            DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime((((from x in xElement.Descendants("Date") select x.Value).First()))),
                            Category = ((from x in xElement.Descendants("Category") select x.Value).First()),
                            Amount = Convert.ToDouble(((from x in xElement.Descendants("Amount") select x.Value).First()))
                        };
                    company.Saleses.Add(sale);
                }
                company.TotalSales = repository.GetTotalSales(company);
                company.AverageSales = repository.AverageSales(company);
                company.TotalMaintenanceFee = repository.MaintenanceFee(company);

                companiesList.AllCompanies.Add(company);


            }
            #endregion
            #region WriteData
            foreach (var xElement in companiesList.AllCompanies)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine("Company Name: " + xElement.Name);
                Console.ResetColor();
                Console.WriteLine("Company Code: "+xElement.Code);
                Console.WriteLine("Company Maintenance percentage: "+xElement.MaintenancePercentage);
                Console.WriteLine("Company Total sales: " + xElement.TotalSales);
                Console.WriteLine("Total maintenance fee: "+ xElement.TotalMaintenanceFee);
                Console.WriteLine("Company Average sales: " + xElement.AverageSales);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                Console.WriteLine("Linked sales:");
                Console.ResetColor();
                foreach (var sale in xElement.Saleses)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Code: "+ sale.Code);
                    Console.WriteLine("Title: " + sale.Title);
                    Console.WriteLine("Date: " + sale.DateTime);
                    Console.WriteLine("Category: " + sale.Category);
                    Console.WriteLine("Amount: " + sale.Amount);
                }
                Console.WriteLine(" ");
            }
            #endregion
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

How do i display the total for matching categories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, group sales by category and then calculate the total amount for each category.

```
var categoryTotals = company.Saleses
            .GroupBy (c => c.Category)
            .Select (
               g => 
                  new  
                  {
                     Category = g.Key, 
                     Total = g.Sum(s => s.Amount)
                  }
            );

foreach(var categoryTotal in categoryTotals)
{
     Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Category: {0}, Total: {1}", 
         categoryTotal.Category, categoryTotal.Total.ToString()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
string iceCreamCategory = "IceCream";
double iceCreamTotal = company.Saleses
    .Where(sale => sale.Category == iceCreamCategory)
    .Sum(sale => sale.Amount);
```

Comment: that sounds awesome but here you know the name of category, but in my actual xml file i have to store name of different category names somehow and check if the category name matches in that variable which holds different category name, and if the name matches then add. What about that?

Comment: Oh, ok. I thought you were just looking for a specific category. In this case, Esteban's answer should do what you want.